# scrape the next pages in python using Beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the links from each page and move on to the next pages and do the same. here is my code to scrape links from the first page:

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 page='https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?objectType=L%C3%A4genhet'

 request = requests.get(page)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml')
 links= soup.findAll('a',class_='search-list__item')

 url=[]
 prefix = "https://www.booli.se"
 for link in links:
    url.append(prefix+link["href"])
```

I tried the following for the first three pages, but it didn't work.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=[]
prefix = "https://www.booli.se"

with requests.Session() as session:

    for page in range(4):
        response = session.get("https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?
        objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=%f" % page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

       links= soup.findAll('a',class_='search-list__item')
       for link in links:
           url.append(prefix+link["href"])
```

Comment: What error occurred or what didn't work ?

Comment: You are doing it only a few times. If you want to scrape all the pages, you need to do it repeatedly as long as you find new at least a new `url`.

Comment: this is jusr an example in a small scale. If I could make it work correctly for 3 pages, I can run it for a bigger loop later. The problem is here, where I expect it to move to the next page but it doesn't do it. with requests.Session() as session:

    for page in range(4):
        response = session.get("https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?
        objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=%f" % page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")                                 My loop to move to the next page is not going through.

Comment: All the 4 pages seem to be same to me.

Comment: `response = session.get("https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?
        objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=%f" % page)`  change this line to `response = session.get("https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?
        objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=" + str(page))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to create code that is working fine with one page.

Then you have to put your scraping code in loop

```
url = "https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=1"
while True:
    code goes here
```

You will notice there is a page=number at the end of the link.
You have to figure to run loop on these url with changing the page=number

```
i=1
url = "https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=" + str(i)
while True:
    i = i+1
    page = requests.get(url)
    if page.status_code != 200:
        break
    url = "https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/?objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page=" + str(i)

    #Your scraping code goes here
    #
    #
```

I have used if statement so that the loop does not goes forever. It will go upto the last page.

Comment: Whatever you said he already did it. It's not going to help him and it's not an answer. Besides you are adding `str(i)` every time with `url` which is incorrect.

Comment: I have used this strategy for scraping, It worked fine. Dont just commment give a useful solution Khairul Basar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did it. Thank you. Here is the code for the first two pages:

```
urls=[]
for page in range(3):
    urls.append("https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/goteborg/22/? 
    objectType=L%C3%A4genhet&page={}".format(page))

page=urls[1:]
#page

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
inturl=[]

for page in page:
    request = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml')
    links= soup.findAll('a',class_='search-list__item')
    prefix = "https://www.booli.se"
    for link in links:
         inturl.append(prefix+link["href"])
```